# need to help to convert

Tags: c#, c++

Hi need help to convert this C++ code to C#

```
sprintf((char *)(dataBuffer), "Failed statistics read, device %s", device);
```

The dataBuffer is byte[]

I wrote this, but with error converting string to byte[]

```
  dataBuffer = string.Format("Failed statistics read, device {0}", device);
```

Comment: That's the right code to convert this statement. What's that about a `byte[]`? There's no byte array in the C++ code.

Comment: @Jonathan Wood A guess (but only a guess) is that dataBuffer is byte[]. Partly supported by the (char *) cast.

Comment: @icktoofay: If that's the case, then the original code is flawed as `%s` is used to format the data, and `%s` is for `char*`. It could be that a byte array was used to store ASCII characters. But that would still be flawed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String str = string.Format("Failed statistics read, device {0}", device);
byte[] dataBuffer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
// for 2-byte unicode
byte[] dataBuffer = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str);
// for UTF8 unicode
byte[] dataBuffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
```